# Assign Date to Missing Cell Based on Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I have a dataframe as below. My question is, i want to assign the missing dates based on the first day of the Month available in the dataset. The dates will only be for a single month per file. It wont be multiple months in a single file. One cell will always have a date.

Please note that the files could be from a previous month so i cant use Today's date. I have used

```
fillna(method='ffill')
```

But this only works if the first cell has a date in it. If its blank itll make the rest blank as well.

*EDIT: The filled dates can be the first of the month or ANY previously populated dates in the column. As long as they are from the same month, it should be fine.*

Sample Data:

| Other Columns | Date | Invoice | Other Columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... |  | ABC232 | ... |
| ... | 5-27-2022 | ABC232 | ... |
| ... | 5-27-2022 | ANBFN2323 | ... |
| ... |  | SADNF343 | ... |
| ... |  | 1232HHH | ... |

Expected Output:

| Other Columns | Date | Invoice | Other Columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 5-01-2022 | ABC232 | ... |
| ... | 5-27-2022 | ABC232 | ... |
| ... | 5-27-2022 | ANBFN2323 | ... |
| ... | 5-01-2022 | SADNF343 | ... |
| ... | 5-01-2022 | 1232HHH | ... |

Please let me know if you have any questions. I cant find anything to even get me started.

Thanks

Comment: Why is the first row filled with `5-27` and the bottom 2 with `5-01`. Your description said "fill with the first day of the month".

Comment: Hi, that was an edit mistake after trying 'ffill'. apologies. it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

# Get the index of the first non-NA Date
idx = df["Date"].first_valid_index()
# Replace the day with 01
fill_value = re.sub(r"(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)", r"\1-01-\3", df.loc[idx, "Date"])
# Fill
df["Date"] = df["Date"].fillna(fill_value)
```